# Overlapping DockStyle.Top Panels

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm Trying do add a new panel with the dock style top to a panel every time a Button is pressed. Every time I press the button the panel gets created and added to the parent, but even though the dockstyle is set to top, they always get added t the exact same location.
I tried to adjust it with *BringToFront* but that made no difference.
Do i have to apply some kind of layout to the parent panel before I can use DockStyle?

Here's My Code:

```
private void AddInputLine()
        {
            this.ButtonFileDialog.Add(this.CreateFileBrowserButton());
            this.TextBoxInput.Add(this.CreateInputTextBox());

            System.Drawing.Size buttonSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.TextBoxInput[^1].Size.Height, this.TextBoxInput[^1].Size.Height);
            this.ButtonFileDialog[^1].MinimumSize = buttonSize;
            this.ButtonFileDialog[^1].MaximumSize = buttonSize;

            this.FormatPanels.Add(new Panel());

            this.FormatPanels[^1].Controls.Add(this.TextBoxInput[^1]);
            this.TextBoxInput[^1].BringToFront();

            this.FormatPanels[^1].Controls.Add(this.ButtonFileDialog[^1]);
            this.ButtonFileDialog[^1].BringToFront();

            this.PanelRightSide.Controls.Add(this.FormatPanels[^1]);
            this.FormatPanels[^1].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you play around with the Form Designer, manually dragging/dropping panels and setting their properties. Then goto the Form1.designer.cs file and copy the generated code from there and use that code to dynamically populate of panels. ps What's with the `^1`?

Comment: Thanks, guess I have to go that way... The ^1 means the index is read backwards, so it gets the last element of the list.

Comment: Instead of abusing the indexer, work with the actual instances of the objects you have just created, then verify what you're actually bringing to front and what you're docking: not the same object. -- The `BringToFront()` / `SendToBack()` layout feature applies to the docked Control, not its child controls. -- I suggest to make use of a FlowLayoutPanel or a TableLayoutPanel to simplify / automate this kind of layout.

Comment: The last one you add goes on top.  So you probably meant this.FormatPanels[^1].BringToFront() to get it to append.  Yes, that gets to be more readable when you use a variable to store the panel reference.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the Problem... The AutoScroll Property of the parent was false. The newly created panels just filled the complete parent, so the others just were not visible. After activating AutoScroll and Auto size it worked. This is the working version of the format panel:

```
this.FormatPanels.Add(new Panel
            {
                BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)Ressources.AppColors.MenuBackground),
                Padding = new Padding(3),
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                AutoSize = true,
                AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
                MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 60),
            });
```

Comment: You may *accept* your own answer once you think it is complete enough (maybe you should add some code sample). This will help other people facing the same problem.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.